# How do I use the SettingsLogic gem in a ruby project?

Tags: ruby, settingslogic

According to the [GitHub](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic) page it's possible to use SettingsLogic in a Ruby project (outside of Rails) but there's no documentation to show you how.

Can anyone provide me with some sample code of how it might work with things like the Rails.env missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a "hello world" example derived from the [specs](https://github.com/binarylogic/settingslogic/tree/master/spec).  First the configuration file *settings.yml*

```
foo: 'hello world'
```

And the code:

```
require 'settingslogic'

class Settings < Settingslogic
  source "#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/settings.yml"
end

p Settings.foo    # => "hello world"
```

Comment: i cant understand the last line p Settings.foo. is it a command line or does it point yml file due to file name.yml or the class name "Settings"

Comment: @user1475089, _p_ is a built-in function that inspects something and prints it.  That is, _p Settings.foo_ is equivalent to _puts Settings.foo.inspect_.